# how to add "new" or "updated" on a view

Tags: views

In my administration content editing page (drupal 7), I have a little red "new " or "updated" next to some items.  How can I make these red labels come out in my views listing?

Comment: How long does the  `updated` text stay there? Will it always show that it has been updated? or is there a certain duration you want to show the `updated` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use field "Content: Has new content" in views to display "updated" text